# Can't figure out how to get new to do list task to render in todo list (React)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm learning as I go. I may have bitten off more than I can chew, which sounds lame since this is just a simple CRUD app. I'm trying to add the todo item to the app when the form is submitted, but I can't remember what the next step should be. Sorry for the ambiguous question, but I'm at a loss right now.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function TodoForm({ addTodo }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
    id: "",
    task: "",
  });

  function addTodo(props) {
    props.onAdd(todo);
    setTodo({
      id: "",
      task: "",
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000);
    event.preventDefault();

    if (todo.task.trim()) {
      addTodo({ ...todo, id });
      setTodo({ ...todo, task: "" });
    }

    console.log({
      id,
      text: input,
    });

    setInput("");
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <header>What do you have to do today?</header>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add a task to your list"
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      ></input>
      <button type="button" value="Submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Add task
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you trying to render each TODO item?

You should start with setting a string array of all TODOs, and then map them in paragraph tag (< p>).

Like this:

```
const [setTodoArray, todoArray] = useState([]);
```

and in the HTML:

```
todoArray.map((todoItem) => <p>{todoItem}</p>)
```